# cannot enter the data every third row and sum 1 column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnMIu.png)cannot input query data every third row on the target google sheets

tried query and appscript

trying to sum column 9 value using the unique values of columns 6,5 and 7 and enter the data every third row on the target sheet from the source.

> 

```js
function queryAndInsertData(D1, D2) {
  var sourceSheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_gI2Hpdk9dN7EBPfI_aGRz24n-cMn8ycGvM7Qv1MSI0/edit#gid=97075253";
  var targetSheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1slEhmuJbxzJQXv4jVujlFpY1sKdGTulYIq8wCba99xQ/edit#gid=1631827415";
  
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourceSheetUrl).getSheetByName("DAILY SUMMARY");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(targetSheetUrl).getSheetByName("TRIAL2");

  // Execute the query
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:CX").getValues();
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var col3Date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[2]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    if (col3Date >= D1 && col3Date <= D2 && row[0] !== "") {
      if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        output.push([row[5], row[4], row[6], row[8]]);
      }
    }
  }

  // Clear existing data in the target range
  targetSheet.getRange("B4:E").clear();

  // Write the output data to the target range every third row
  for (var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
    targetSheet.getRange(4 + j * 3, 2, 1, output[j].length).setValues([output[j]]);
  }
}

queryAndInsertData("2024-02-05", "2024-02-16");
```

Comment: [Edit] to show your query and apps script. Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings.  "2024-02-05" is a string.  The value from `Utilities.formatDate()` is a string.  In order to do a numerical comparison of dates, you would need to use date objects.

Try this.  I created a test sheet as shown below.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test2");
    let d1 = new Date("2024-02-05");
    // or let d1 = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
    let d2 = new Date("2024-02-16");
    // or let d2 = sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for( let i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
      if( ( values[i][0] >= d1 ) && ( values[i][0] <= d2 ) ) {
        if( ((i+1) % 3) === 0 ) {
          console.log(i)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
6:50:49 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:50:49 AM  Info    5
6:50:49 AM  Info    8
6:50:49 AM  Info    11
6:50:49 AM  Info    14
6:50:50 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```